# On an Android device is there a way to programmatically get the USB serial number as shown in ADB?

Tags: android, usb, serial-number

On an Android device is there a way to programmatically get the USB serial number as shown in ADB?

Secure.getString(mApp.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID) is different then what is shown in ADB.

EDIT: Note the date of this question.  It was asked before there was android.os.Build.SERIAL;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to obtain serial number is :

```
String deviceSerialNumberFromADB = android.os.Build.SERIAL;
```

This serial number equals to: "adb get-serialno" or "adb devices" from command prompt (if only 1 device connected).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is:

```
adb shell cat /sys/class/android_usb/android0/iSerial
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here. If you wanted to get the serial number via the command line, you could run:

```
adb get-serialno
```

If you wanted to somehow get this information within your app, have a look through [AdbDevice.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/USB/AdbTest/src/com/android/adb/AdbDevice.html).

Using a `UsbDeviceConnection` object, you can:

```
// UsbDeviceConnection connection
serialNo = connection.getSerial();
Log.d(TAG, "Serial number is: " +serialNo);
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  The sample AdbTest shows how to do that... unfortunately it uses a class that isn't available until version 12.